# Tying Paypal Settlement Report Back to Specific Order Object

Tags: paypal, magento-1, reports

Is there any known science for tying the information in the PayPal settlement report table

```
paypal_settlement_report_row
```

back to a specific Magento order object?

Comment: Could you use a `Varien_Object` of the data and use one of the Order/Quote methods in `Mage_Sales_Model_Convert_Quote`?

Comment: @B00MER I'm not sure I understand the comment.  I want to know which of the PayPal settlement rows relate back to which existing Magento order.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you wanted a way to create a quote/order back from the Paypal data. According to this it should be the `invoice_id`. https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/PP_LRD_Gen_SettlementReport.pdf